# Hyperledger relation between user and peers

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

If I want to develop a system like bitcoin using hyperledger, in this system each user must be associated with one validating peer?

Answer (score 5):

In Fabric 1.0, a end user is not associated with a peer. A user may leverage an application to interface with the network to transact. The application may be a mobile app or a webapp, which either passes the user's identity through or acts on behalf of the user. For example, a user may use a banking application, which interacts with the network via the SDK. The application would pass the user's identity on the network; that is, every transaction made by the user would bear the user's identity and signature. On the other hand, the application may act on behalf of the user and issue the transaction using its own identity and signature.

Hyperledger Fabric differentiates members from users. Members participate on the network and have peers and orderers or applications running on the network. For example, several banks may set up a Fabric network, so they are the members of the network, and their customers could be the users of the network. The banks would deploy many peers and orderers to accommodate the traffic demand from their customers, but it would not be 1 peer to 1 user.